# PFTwitterUtils error when using Parse.com API - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and its `PFTwitterUtils` to integrate Twitter Login in my app. When trying to fetch user's Twitter details after successful login, this line of code doesn't seem to work. (The code has been taken from [Official Parse Twitter integration Guidelines](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-twitter-users))

[image]

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `PF_Twitter` class has been declared using `@class PF_Twitter;` but no interface has been found. You need to include the header.

Add this at the top of your file :

```
#import <ParseTwitterUtils/PF_Twitter.h>
```

Alternatively, you can also add the following line :

```
#import <ParseTwitterUtils/ParseTwitterUtils.h>
```

and remove this one :

```
#import <ParseTwitterUtils/PFTwitterUtils.h>
```